# Windows defender flags my `Golang Tray Application` as virus program

Tags: windows, go, windows-defender

I have a question about the windows defender problem with my golang application.

I've developed a tray application in Go, its general purpose is serving features that run the server on local device, so every teammates in my team can run the server even when I was in the office.

It is only deployed by my team slack channel after I built it as `.exe` file.

The below is portion of my project, I removed `host` and `port`.

```
package main

import (
    "Go-Tray/icon"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type serverType int

const (
    dclo serverType = iota
    admin
)

type serverInfo struct {
    serverType
    host      string
    port      string
    isRunning bool
}

func main() {
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetIcon(icon.GetIconData("blackAndWhite.ico"))
    systray.SetTitle("D-Clo Local Server")
    systray.SetTooltip("D-Clo Local Server")
    dcloStart := systray.AddMenuItem("Start Dclo", "Run D-clo Api Local Server")
    dcloStop := systray.AddMenuItem("Stop Dclo", "Stop D-clo Api Local Server")
    adminStart := systray.AddMenuItem("Start Admin", "Run Admin Api Local Server")
    adminStop := systray.AddMenuItem("Stop Admin", "Stop Admin Api Local Server")
    systray.AddSeparator()
    mQuit := systray.AddMenuItem("Quit", "Quit the whole app")

    dcloServerInfo := serverInfo{
        host:       "",
        port:       "",
        serverType: dclo,
        isRunning:  false,
    }
    adminServerInfo := serverInfo{
        host:       "",
        port:       "",
        serverType: admin,
        isRunning:  false,
    }

    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    go func() {
        for range ticker.C {
            dcloServerInfo.isRunning = checkServerStatus(dcloServerInfo)
            adminServerInfo.isRunning = checkServerStatus(adminServerInfo)

            if !dcloServerInfo.isRunning && !adminServerInfo.isRunning {
                systray.SetIcon(icon.GetIconData("blackAndWhite.ico"))
                systray.SetTooltip("Every server is stopped")
                dcloStart.Show()
                dcloStop.Hide()
                adminStart.Show()
                adminStop.Hide()
                continue
            } else {
                systray.SetIcon(icon.GetIconData("default.ico"))
            }

            if dcloServerInfo.isRunning {
                dcloStart.Hide()
                dcloStop.Show()
                if adminServerInfo.isRunning {
                    adminStart.Hide()
                    adminStop.Show()
                    systray.SetTooltip("Servers(Dclo, Admin) are running")
                } else {
                    adminStart.Show()
                    adminStop.Hide()
                    systray.SetTooltip("Dclo server is running")
                }
            } else {
                dcloStart.Show()
                dcloStop.Hide()
                adminStart.Hide()
                adminStop.Show()
                systray.SetTooltip("Admin server is running")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-dcloStart.ClickedCh:
                resp, err := http.Get("")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                    systray.Quit()
                    return
                }
                resp.Body.Close()
                break
            case <-dcloStop.ClickedCh:
                resp, err := http.Get("")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                    systray.Quit()
                    return
                }
                resp.Body.Close()
                break
            case <-adminStart.ClickedCh:
                resp, err := http.Get("")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                    systray.Quit()
                    return
                }
                resp.Body.Close()
                break
            case <-adminStop.ClickedCh:
                resp, err := http.Get("")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                    systray.Quit()
                    return
                }
                resp.Body.Close()
                break
            case <-mQuit.ClickedCh:
                ticker.Stop()
                systray.Quit()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func onExit() {
}

func checkServerStatus(info serverInfo) bool {
    timeout := 1 * time.Second
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(info.host, info.port), timeout)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    if conn != nil {
        defer conn.Close()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I used `getlantern/systray` package for developing windows tray icon application.

I've seen that it works well on my local device, and I've seen that it works even when I download it directly after it's been deployed on slack. However, when a team member who uses the same environment as me downloaded the file 'exe' built on slack, Windows defender blocks it.

I want to know the cause of this phenomenon, but with my level of knowledge, it's hard to even know where to check.

If anyone has experienced something similar or has any knowledge, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's likely that this is a false positive. i.e. Something it is doing has triggered an alert in Windows Defender, even though the activity is innocuous. Once you are sure that you don't have a virus you can [whitelist your app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26#:~:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Update,%2C%20file%20types%2C%20or%20process.).

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks for your advice! Thankfully my team members agreed to use it with checking it as whitelist. I should learn about false positive problem. :)

Comment: False positives are a fact of life with Windows virus detectors no matter who makes them.  Not much you can do about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom This was rare experience to me, I've searched about it and there are lots of cases. But I'm curious how can I say this is `false positive` or not by reading my codes.

Comment: «…say this is false positive or not by reading my codes»—the usual approach employed by A/V software is scoring based on heuristics. Say, initially any executable image found is assigned some pessimistic score. It is then found to be digitally signed? The score is rised. It can be seen that the binary was installed as an MSI package? The score is rised. Installed under %ProgramFiles%? Rised. Looks like an installer created by one of the known pieces of software? Up. And so on and so forth. Conversely, an executable image file suddenly appeared somewhere under your %USERPROFILE% is suspicious.

Comment: For added fun, you can learn than high-profile A/V products [still sometimes mark official Windows builds of the Git version control tool as being a virus/malware](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20240125162117.ajysmqwrqc4emybn@carbon/).